# While using the console.log command, my code hasn't shown up in the console

Tags: javascript, html, console, command, console.log

[image]

As shown on the top left, the code is transferred on by opening the code in a separate file via chrome. The vs. code tab is where the raw code is displayed. Unfortunately, after incorporating the console.log command and applying an equation, the answer did not show up in the console.

Comment: Alert blocks execution of further code. So place it At the end or close the alert to see the result

Answer (score 1):

Each browser tab has it's own console corresponding to the content in its tab.

Based on your screenshot, it appears you have the console open for the Udemy website, but you need to open the console for your JavaScript Fundamentals - Part 1 tab in order to see any console logs from the code you wrote.

You can generally open the console in any tab/window using F12 and clicking on the Console tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem, definitely will come back to this website in case I have any more complications. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you sure you are inspecting the same page as the one you're asking.
there is no compilation error, if it was then pop would have not shown at first place.
try a semicolon after consol.log statement, hope that might work.